# need to copy external jar files in glassfish 3.1.2 domain lib directory

Tags: java, glassfish

I am trying to deploy an ear application  Glassfish 3.1.2 however I am not able to as it throw exception "class not found" however i was able to deploy the same ear application on Glassfish 2.1.1.
When i copy all relevant jar files under <>/lib directory then it works.
why I get error deploying ear on GF312 while same application can be deployed on GF211 without including jar file as mentioned in above location.
I am using jdk7.

Could anyone please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is due to the jaxb jar present in galssfish/module directory